Best option to (EVM compatible) Bitcoin Layer 2 Smart Contracts on Solidity?
I would like to migrate some Smart Contracts written in Solidity, and deployed on top of Ethereum and Polygon, to an EVM compatible Bitcoin layer 2.
I see there are different options, but not sure about real adoption of those networks, neither their technical maturity and real roadmap.
Any suggestion?
